# Область видимости Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть два фрагмента кода:

```
lst=[4,5,6]

def foo(lst):
    lst.append('elem')

foo(lst)
print(lst)
```

и:

```
lst=[4,5,6]

def foo(lst):
    lst=[1,2,3]

foo(lst)
print(lst)
```

Как я понял, в Python значения всегда передаются по ссылке.

Почему тогда во втором примере `lst` не изменился?
Это связано с областями видимости переменных?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во втором примере Вы присвоили параметру `lst` (ссылке на объект) внутри функции `foo` другое значение, и она (переменная) стала указывать на новый объект, но значение наружной переменной `lst` (ссылки) от этого не изменилось.

В первом примере - Вы изменили свойства/содержимое объекта, на который указывает ссылка, переданная в функцию, но объект остался по тому же адресу. Значение самой ссылки осталось тем же.

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь нет - не всегда значения передаются по ссылке - это работает только для объектов

```
>>> x = 5
>>> def f(x):
...   x = 6
... 
>>> f(x)
>>> x
5
```

В своем первом примере вы на самом деле передали объект по ссылке и изменили то, что лежит по этой ссылке. Это можно наглядно увидеть используя функцию id:

```
lst=[4,5,6]
print(id(lst))
def foo(lst):
    print(id(lst))
    lst.append('elem')
    print(id(lst))

foo(lst)
print(lst)
```

Результат будет:

```
4390272008
4390272008
4390272008
[4, 5, 6, 'elem']
```

Во втором же случае - именно из области видимости вы не поменяли объект, а создали новый. В результате этого вы переопредили глобальный. Опять же - это наглядно видно с помощью команды id:

```
lst=[4,5,6]
print(id(lst))
def foo(lst):
    print(id(lst))
    lst = [1, 2, 3]
    print(id(lst))

foo(lst)
print(lst)
```

Результат:

```
4389548104
4389548104
4389549960
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

В первом примере вы применили метод для изменения списка *на месте*:

```
lst.append('elem')
```

пока во втором вы переменной `lst` присвоили *новый список*

```
lst=[1,2,3]
```

чем вы удалили ссылку на его оригинальное значение (`[4,5,6]`), *но только внутри функции* `foo()`.